# Add columns to SqlWebEventProvider

Tags: asp.net, health-monitoring

In an ASP.NET application, we'd like to use the `SqlWebEventProvider` to log any Event that occurs during the application lifetime.

The problem is that we think that the table `aspnet_WebEvent_Event` doesn't provide enough columns and should log more information (we need to keep the Logged user).
I'm aware that this information could be stored in the "**Details**" column but it wouldn't then be really simple to filter the results and build reports.

So I'm searching for a simple solution to add a column. I wish I could derive `SqlWebEventProvider` but the methods used to build the stored procedure parameters are private (`PrepareParams()` and `FillParams()`).

Any simple solution that doesn't imply to rewrite the entire Provider class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching it seems that it is not possible without inheriting from the existing `SqlWebEventProvider` and overriding the methods properly to insert the values.

You can look into the .NET Framework code to check for the current implementation with [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding columns to the SqlWebEventProvider and it's table default schema, you may consider creating your own WebEventProvider that logs events to a database of your own schema.

Here is an introductory reference on how to do so.
http://bit.ly/2fXeuH